# Remove Sony-HDR password from wifi API

Tags: api, passwords, wifi, sony

My app needs to communicate to the Sony HDR-AS20 via Wi-Fi. The user connects to the camera, creates a video and ends the connection. I would like the connection with the HDR to be open, without a password. Is there anyway I can remove the password or automatically send the password via the API when user tries to connect to the camera? What are the possibilities around an open public connection?

Thanks,
Mitchell

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you need to remove the password or automatically send it.  When the user first connects their phone to the camera over WiFi it will ask for a password (or using NFC they don't even need to enter a WiFi password) but after that future connections do not require a password to be entered since the phone saves the WiFi PW.  So I would recommend just mentioning in your app description or README that the user should connect to WiFi once first and then they can use the app after that without worrying about entering a PW everytime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We also expected people to understand this. However, during tests we noticed that a majority, didn't understand this. We referred to the pass multiple times in the app. That is why we need the Wi-Fi password to be removed, is there any way we can do this? Using NFC is something we are looking in to at the moment. However for this we would like to have NFC activated all the time, which only seems to work by pressing on the N mark button on the HDR. Is there any way we can activate the NFC in the HDR via the SDK, without touching the camera itself? @MarlinSONY

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, removing the password is not supported and neither is activating NFC on the HDR via the SDK.